# Chrome becomes unusable after viewing intranet site

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion

I have been working with my IT department to figure out what is going on, but was curious if anybody in the community had an idea. I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on OSX 10.8.2, and when I visit certain intranet sites for Ariba.com, not only does the site I'm trying to reach timeout, but it permanently causes Chrome to timeout for any other site thereafter. This problem persists, even if I quit and restart Chrome, and/or restart my ethernet using ifconfig. The only solution is to restart my computer.

Unfortunately, I can't include the intranet link, but I was hoping somebody might have experienced something like this before or understand the workings of Chrome enough to make a stab at it.

Comment: We have no way of knowing whats going on within your intranet.  How is this not to localized to this author?

Comment: If you have an HTTP proxy, maybe check its configuration script.

Comment: Daniel, I do not have a proxy setup. Ramhound, I know, I am hoping somebody else has experienced something like this. The issue does affect other OSX developers as well.

Comment: @Ramhound Would it be too localized if a member of the IT department posted asking why their intranet site broke Mac's who run Chrome?  The only difference I can see is that, as it's posted now, we probably can't get details regarding the server/switch configs.